# How to pass a url as parameter for curl get request

Tags: curl, get

I am trying to pass a url as a parameter for curl get request. I am able to pass a simple text as a parameter but when I try to pass a url its not working. Please help me .

See below the url I am trying to get

curl -X GET http://localhost:3003/getresourcedata/**http%3A%FA%FA10.x.x.x%3A8080%FA...**

highlighted bold is the parameter I'm trying to pass.

If I try the below url it works fine.

http://localhost:3003/getresourcedata/**ABCD**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vara

Comment: you're not escaping properly. how to escape it depends on what kind of shell you're using. would probably be better just to write a script for it, which makes escaping a breeze. like in PHP, `$ch=curl_init();curl_setopt_array($ch,[CURLOPT_URL=>'http://localhost:3003/getresourcedata/'.curl_escape($ch,'http%3A%FA%FA10.x.x.x%3A8080%FA...'),CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1]);curl_exec($ch);`